# libkmod ERROR and parsing module name '['

Tags: drivers, kernel

I am getting the following error when running lsmod/(and other kmod related commands):

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:489 kcmdline_parse_result: Ignoring bad option on kernel command line while parsing module name: '['
```

- Can I somehow find out where this module name is trying to be parsed?
- How can I find why this is caused?
- Is there a way to debug this?

Notes:

- I uninstalled any nvidia drivers
- System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- kernel : 5.3.0-51-generic

Output of `grep -Fr '[' /sys/modules` :

```
Binary file /sys/module/r8169/notes/.note.gnu.build-id matches
Binary file /sys/module/snd_hda_codec_hdmi/notes/.note.gnu.build-id matches
Binary file /sys/module/snd_hwdep/notes/.note.gnu.build-id matches
Binary file /sys/module/dell_wmi/notes/.note.gnu.build-id matches
Binary file /sys/module/intel_rapl_perf/notes/.note.gnu.build-id matches
/sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policy:[default] performance powersave powersupersave 
Binary file /sys/module/mac80211/notes/.note.gnu.build-id matches
Binary file /sys/module/aes_x86_64/notes/.note.gnu.build-id matches
Binary file /sys/module/ttm/notes/.note.gnu.build-id matches
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_INIT                0x00000001 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_DEBUG_OBJECT        0x00000002 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_INFO                0x00000004 [*]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_REPAIR              0x00000008 [*]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_TRACE_POINT         0x00000010 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_INIT_NAMES          0x00000020 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_PARSE               0x00000040 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_LOAD                0x00000080 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_DISPATCH            0x00000100 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_EXEC                0x00000200 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_NAMES               0x00000400 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_OPREGION            0x00000800 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_BFIELD              0x00001000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_TABLES              0x00002000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_VALUES              0x00004000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_OBJECTS             0x00008000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_RESOURCES           0x00010000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_USER_REQUESTS       0x00020000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_PACKAGE             0x00040000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_ALLOCATIONS         0x00100000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_FUNCTIONS           0x00200000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_OPTIMIZATIONS       0x00400000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_MUTEX               0x01000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_THREADS             0x02000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_IO                  0x04000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_INTERRUPTS          0x08000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_AML_DISASSEMBLE     0x10000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_VERBOSE_INFO        0x20000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_FULL_TABLES         0x40000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_level:ACPI_LV_EVENTS              0x80000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_UTILITIES              0x00000001 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_HARDWARE               0x00000002 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_EVENTS                 0x00000004 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_TABLES                 0x00000008 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_NAMESPACE              0x00000010 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_PARSER                 0x00000020 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_DISPATCHER             0x00000040 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_EXECUTER               0x00000080 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_RESOURCES              0x00000100 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_CA_DEBUGGER            0x00000200 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_OS_SERVICES            0x00000400 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_CA_DISASSEMBLER        0x00000800 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_COMPILER               0x00001000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_TOOLS                  0x00002000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_BUS_COMPONENT          0x00010000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_AC_COMPONENT           0x00020000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_BATTERY_COMPONENT      0x00040000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_BUTTON_COMPONENT       0x00080000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_SBS_COMPONENT          0x00100000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_FAN_COMPONENT          0x00200000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_PCI_COMPONENT          0x00400000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_POWER_COMPONENT        0x00800000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_CONTAINER_COMPONENT    0x01000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_SYSTEM_COMPONENT       0x02000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_THERMAL_COMPONENT      0x04000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_MEMORY_DEVICE_COMPONENT    0x08000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_VIDEO_COMPONENT        0x10000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_PROCESSOR_COMPONENT    0x20000000 [ ]
/sys/module/acpi/parameters/debug_layer:ACPI_ALL_DRIVERS            0xFFFF0000 [ ]
```

Comment: Does `grep -Fr '[' /etc/modprobe.d/` output anything?

Comment: @steeldriver Thx for you response, unfortunately not.  I  had tried something similar in there

Comment: What is the output of `sudo grep -Fr '[' /sys/module/` ?

Comment: @Raffa I posted the results inside the post

Comment: @akarapatis The output of `sudo grep -Fr '[' /sys/module/` looks OK. Please run `cat /proc/cmdline` and `cat /etc/default/grub` and show the output. The error says bad option on [kernel command line](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/kernel-command-line.7.html)

Comment: @Raffa Here is the culprit ```/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-51-generic root=UUID=0d6a9d40-2721-4928-9f7c-bdead6fb5c6f ro nomodeset nogpumanager i915.modeset=1 [...]```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is check the command line passed to the kernel

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

Then edit the grub file `/etc/default/grub`, fix the wrong arguments and run `sudo update-grub`

Credits
@Raffa